# jquery popup is not shown when i place the content inside the update panel

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, updatepanel

i have a grid and edit delete button when i select any row then click on the edit or delete button that perticular row is show in the jquery pop. but when i place the grid into the asp update panel the popup is not shown
the script used is as

```
 function ShowPopup() {
        $('#mask').show();
        $('#<%=pnlpopup.ClientID %>').show();
    }
    function HidePopup() {
        $('#mask').hide();
        $('#<%=pnlpopup.ClientID %>').hide();
    }
    $(".btnClose").live('click', function () {
        HidePopup();
    });
```

where 'pnlpopup' is the asp panel in which the popup is shown

and on the code page i have popup function

```
    void Popup1(bool isDisplay)
    {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        if (isDisplay)
        {
            builder.Append("<script language=JavaScript> ShowPopup(); </script>\n");
            Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "ShowPopup", builder.ToString());
        }
        else
        {
            builder.Append("<script language=JavaScript> HidePopup(); </script>\n");
            Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "HidePopup", builder.ToString());
        }
    }
```

and on edit_button click this function is called

thanks

Comment: What does your UpdatePanel markup look like?

Answer (score 0):

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(Page), UniqueID, "alert('hi')", true);
```

try this more detailed example here http://weblogs.asp.net/infinitiesloop/archive/2007/09/17/inline-script-inside-an-asp-net-ajax-updatepanel.aspx

Comment: this does't work when i click on the edit button no any popup is shown please provide code if you can